# Alternatives to using cursor for updating a database based on a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, database-cursor

Maybe that title isnt really enlightening but i couldnt come with a less contrived one. Here is my problem:

Im working with a table that has data that looks like

```
id  cId        ver      active
1   100         1       0    
2   100         2       1    
3   100         3       1    
4   200         1       0    
5   200         2       1    
6   300         1       1
```

For this table, Id is the PK and cId identifies a client. basically we are storing versioning history.

The problem im trying to solve is to update the db to set active =1 only for the most recent version which is the highest [ver] per client. (the client with cId 100 is bugged in the example)

Now, i have managed to write the following query that gives me the data to work on with

```
select t.id, t.cId,t.version 
from (select *
      from comp.Clients  a
      where a.ver = (select max(b.ver) from comp.Clients b where a.cId=b.cIdentifier)
    ) t
```

From that point my solution is to plug that query on a cursor and for each record on the cursor i would update the table to active=0 and active =1 for the current record.

the thing is cursors are what they are, is there something that gives me a decent performance here? im not good with CTEs so i couldnt come up with a solution that revolves around that. The actual table has some 10k records and some 50 fields.

Comment: why can't we use 2 update statements for this scenario? We can write one update to update the active flag to 0 and a second one to update the max version for a client to 1

Comment: you should see my face right now, between exhasperation and laughter. that really is a very simple and effective solution. can you change your comment to an answer?

Comment: Done. Updated the answer with my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should find last `ver` for each `CId` then update your table

```
select cId,Max(ver) as MaxVer into #tmpTable from comp.Clients  group by cid

update c
set active = case when t.cId is not null then 1 else 0 end
from comp.Clients c left join #tmpTable t on t.CId=c.CId and t.MaxVer=c.ver
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a cursor, use 2 updates. One to update the values to 0 and another to set the latest version for the client ID to 1. This should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select c.*,
             max(ver) over (partition by CId) as max_ver
      from comp.Clients c
     )
update toupdate
    set active = (case when max_ver = ver then 1 else 0 end);
```

You can add a `where` clause to limit the number of rows being updated, if you like:

```
   where active <> (case when max_ver = ver then 1 else 0 end)
```